# Running a program/task for all users?

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-desktop, autoit, powershell-remoting

Is it possible (with autoit or any other language) to run a program for ALL logged in users (not at startup, at a time when I define) including remote desktop users (windows 7) at the same time?

Furthermore is it possible to log users in from the console?

Comment: If you know them try using RunAs. Or try using the PStools like http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Comment: That's more of a Windows specific question...

Answer (score 1):

I would think creating a Scheduled Task preference item in Group Policy might be your best bet.  This would allow you to select a scope of users and when to run your program.  I think you can even run the program on demand and only if the user is logged in on Win 7 platforms.